# Text of Text Box Based on ComboBox Item in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I hv a Combobox in my Application in which Comboboxitems are "Yes" and 'No'
I want to assign Text of my text box as "cleared" if Comboboxitem yes is Selected And "not cleared" if Comboboxitem "No" is Selected how Do I do That on WPF

Comment: yes/no combobox? use a checkbox instead!

Comment: This is Question to get Idea of Combobox and text box integration my actual application is more complex therefore I need to use combobox there

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it entirely in XAML, you could use an [element binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.elementname.aspx) on the TextBox (to the checkbox/combobox), and then implement a [value converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752091.aspx) to convert the Yes/No to the appropriate string.

Alternatively, if using MVVM, you could bind the checkbox `IsChecked` or combobox `SelectedValue` to a property on your view model, and in that properties setter, notify another property which is your text box text, which has just a getter which returns the appropriate string based on your first view model property.  Bind your TextBox `Text` property to this new view model property.

Comment: I Did it this way  But after Selection it is just showinig not cleared selecting either yes or no when we run the application
private void comboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.Equals("yes"))
            {
                textBox32.Text = "cleared";
            }
            else { textBox32.Text = "not cleared"; }
        }

Comment: Could you add the code that populates your combobox, it sounds like you want to do a comparison on the SelectedValue, and not the SelectedItem.

Answer (score 1):

Create an implementation of IValueConverter

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace XAMLConverter
{
    public class ComboBoxConverter : IValueConverter
    {


        object IValueConverter.Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            try
            {                
                if (value.ToString() == "Yes")
                    return "Cleared";
                else if (value.ToString() == "No")
                    return "Not Cleared";
                else
                    return "";

            }
            catch
            {
                return "";
            }
        }

        object IValueConverter.ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Add your namespace to the XAML for:

```
xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:XAMLConverter"
```

Add a resource for the converter:

```
<Window.Resources>        
    <conv:ComboBoxConverter x:Key="ComboBoxConverter" />        
</Window.Resources>
```

Then add your controls:

```
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox Name="SelectControl">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Yes" />
            <ComboBoxItem Content="No" />
        </ComboBox>

        <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=SelectControl, 
                                Path=SelectedItem.Content, 
                                Converter={StaticResource ComboBoxConverter}}" 
        />

    </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

Trigger solution goes here:

```
        <ComboBox Name="cb">
            <ComboBoxItem>Yes</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>No</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
        <TextBox>
            <TextBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=cb, Path=SelectedItem.Content}" Value="Yes">
                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="cleared"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=cb, Path=SelectedItem.Content}" Value="No">
                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="not cleared"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBox.Style>
        </TextBox>
```