# Datatrigger change property of another element

Tags: c#, wpf

I have combobox and textbox. When I change selected item of combobox I want to change property of textbox by some conditions of combobox object and I dont know how.

Here is my code:

xaml

```
<ComboBox x:Name="someItems" Style="{StaticResource comboBoxItems}" />
<TextBox x:Name="myTextBox" />
```

app.xaml

```
    <Style x:Key="comboBoxItems" TargetType="ComboBox">
         <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
            <Setter.Value>
                  <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                       <Style.Triggers>                          
                           <DataTrigger >
//here is missing the binding code
                               <Setter Property="somepropertyoftextboxobject" Value="somevalue"/>
                           </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                   </Style>
             </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
     </Style>
```

Comment: can this be a solution? https://stackoverflow.com/a/4957508/856777

Answer (score 1):

```xml
    <ComboBox x:Name="cBox" ItemsSource="{Binding ....}"/>
    <TextBox>
        <TextBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem.SomeProperty, ElementName=cBox}"
                                    Value="SomeValue">
                        <!--Setters for TextBox-->
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem.SomeProperty, ElementName=cBox}"
                                    Value="OtherValue">
                        <!--Setters for TextBox-->
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Style>
    </TextBox>
```